# How to continuously deliver data to the same request

Tags: node.js, express, stream, backend

I am relatively new to back end technologies and I was amazed by the example I've seen today.

This is an example that introduces a new API, but I was amazed by how data was delivered over the same request. I possibly suspect that streams were used I tried to create it with `res.write` method of the express but it's not really doing what I want. It doesn't send the response until whole stream is read.

https://fetch-abort-demo.glitch.me/

How could I implement this in an Node.JS / Express app?

Comment: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io

Comment: @JDunken as I know every time socket sends a message a new request appears in the `network` tab? I am so genius I check `network` tab but not the actual source code at the `elements` tab. It gives more information but I can tell socket isn't used here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was right about stream. I couldn't read it properly before because it requires some client-side code to read streamed data. The source code for reading can be found in the example link I've posted.

And the stream looks like this.

```js
const it = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']

app.get('/stream', (req, res) => {
  let time = 100
  for (const i of it) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      res.write(i)
    }, time)
    time += 2000
  }
  setTimeout(() => {
    res.end()
  }, time + 2000)
})
```